# Salt: text file to variable and use the same variable in state file to find&replace

Tags: salt-stack

I've run into an issue I havent been able to solve:
I have a file(/etc/osci) that I use on all of my servers as an name for our monitoring(zabbix) 
I've created a state file that pushes a template configuration file to the server and and reads the content of /etc/osci to a variable. The next step would be to use that same variable with 'file.replace' function to search for a string and replace it with the variable.

```html
uusnimi=$(cat /etc/osci):
 cmd.run

/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf:
 file.managed:
  - source: salt://base/streamingconf/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
  - mode: 644


change_hostname_zabbix:
 file.replace:
  - name: /etc/zabbix_agentd.conf
  - pattern: 'Hostname='
  - repl: 'Hostname=$uusnimi'
```

Now when executing the state file echoing the variable in the target server it provides me the right output:

```html
echo $uusnimi
Server1
```

but for the life of me I can't figure out how to escape the last line of the above code so it would insert the value not the '$uusnimi' string

Answer (score 5):

**Use uusnimi as a jinja variable.**

```
{% set uusnimi = salt['cmd.shell']('cat /etc/osci') %}

/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf:
 file.managed:
  - source: salt://base/streamingconf/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
  - mode: 644

change_hostname_zabbix:
 file.replace:
  - name: /etc/zabbix_agentd.conf
  - pattern: 'Hostname='
  - repl: 'Hostname={{ uusnimi }}'
```

Comment: Hmm, I was aware of the possibility of defined variables in state files but did not know you are able to assign them this way, many thanks, :)

Comment: Hope that the answer can help you :)